# How can I read Digital Elevation Model?

Tags: dem, android

I downloaded a Digital Elevation Model of Mexico from [here](http://www.inegi.org.mx/geo/contenidos/datosrelieve/continental/descarga.aspx), and when I extracted the .rar, I got these files: `Republica30_R60m.bil`, `Republica30_R60m.hdr`, `Republica30_R60m.prj` and `Republica30_R60m.stx`.

I need to be able to read this for an Android App, but I haven't found any information about how to read these files.

Can anyone tell me how to read it or where I can find information about it?

Comment: The Perl scripts at my https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/DEM/ may or may not be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Band interleaved by line (BIL) files and it's associated header file (HDR) are raster format files.  The PRJ file is a projection file, telling a GIS software application where in space to draw the file.
I don't know how to read the BIL file with an Android friendly library but you could use something like QGIS to convert the BIL file to another file format.
Here are some links:
[From ESRI](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?topicname=BIL,_BIP,_and_BSQ_raster_files),
[US Government info on BIL](http://www.digitalpreservation.gov/formats/fdd/fdd000304.shtml)